# Setting up Django in Heroku database error

Tags: python, django, heroku

Is my first time using django, and i wanted to deploy it in heroku. i am getting the next error "config['DATABASES']['default'] = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=MAX_CONN_AGE, ssl_require=True)
TypeError: config() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ssl_require'" when i run

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

I have tried doing the deployment following this guide that sould make the local database be sqlite3 and production postgresql https://medium.com/@BennettGarner/deploying-django-to-heroku-procfile-static-root-other-pitfalls-e7ab8b2ba33b
i would actually like to set up both databases to postgresql, because i have it install in my local machine

This is settings.py

```py
import os
import dj_database_url
import dotenv
import django_heroku

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myapp.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myapp.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {'default': {}}
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser' 
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

django_heroku.settings(locals())

del DATABASES['default']['OPTIONS']['sslmode']
```

This is the .env

```
DATABASE_URL=sqlite:///db.sqlite3
```

This is the Procfile

```
web: gunicorn grupo1-llevame.wsgi --log-file -
```

I would like that the migration passes and i dont found any advice so i decided to ask here any sugestion in how i nake the question is apreciated, this is just the second time i used the site.

Also when running

```
python migrate.py runserver
```

it shows this error "del DATABASES['default']['OPTIONS']['sslmode']
KeyError: 'OPTIONS'"

Comment: Well why are you doing that? Get rid of that `del` line.

Comment: i have removed that line and the problem disapear, but it is still not solved, i think i have set badly the database because it doesnt work in local nor in production. in local it gives me the error that the database engine is missing

Answer (score 1):

heroku does not allow the use of sqlite in production. Use postgresql instead.